# try/catch and return

Tags: language-agnostic

What solution do you prefer?
I prefer solution 2, but I am wondering if exists a better practice
Thank you all

Solution 1 - try/catch nested

```
try
{
   //some code that could throws Exception1
   try
   {
        //some code that could throws Exception2
        return success;
   }      
   catch (Exception2 e)
   {
      return failure;
   }
}
catch (Exception1 e)
{
  return failure;
}
```

Solution 2 - try/catch sequential

```
try
{
   //some code that could throws Exception1 
}
catch (Exception1 e)
{
  return failure;
}

try
{
    //some code that could throws Exception2
}      
catch (Exception2 e)
{
  return failure;
}

return success;
```

Comment: Prefer 2, except when throwing int values, as an alternative to goto.

Comment: It can't just be determined until you you demonstrate it with a situation. Beware handling **unchecked** exceptions in this way is indeed a very bad idea.

Comment: Better fit for code review stackexchange site?

Answer (score 1):

-4! I think it's a reasonable question myself, especially for someone just starting out.
Why is it such a bad question?

Personally I'd use the code below unless there is a compelling reason not to.

```
try
{
   //some code that could throws Exception1 
   //some code that could throws Exception2
   //some code that could throws Exception3
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  return failure;
}
```

Comment: _"What solution do you prefer?"_ is not an objective question. The FAQ has full details on what type of questions can be asked here, if you're not sure that's the best place to look

Comment: Handling this verbose exception - `Exception` is the worst thing that says - "*You're not sure about the code you wrote - what exception in your code is caused when.*"

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
try
{
   //some code that could throws Exception1 
   //some code that could throws Exception2
}
catch (Exception1 e)
{
   return failure;
}
catch (Exception2 e)
{
   return failure;
}

return success;
```